# Вызов вложенных файлов .php из каталогов

Tags: php

На сайте в корне собралось очень много файлов some.php отвечающие за отображение страница (сайт на чистом php, без фреймворков) Есть важные страницы, такие как index.php и второстепенные вроде dev.php

На всех страницах сайта выводится хедер через `require 'includes/header.php';` и все превосходно работает как на index.php так и на dev.php

Однако все второстепенные страницы (например) я задумал перенести в отдельный каталог /go/
и вот теперь при вызове хедера возникают проблемы, так как сам хедер тоже имеет разные инклуды (nav.php, stat.php, etc..)

Вопрос, есть ли магический способ сделать так, что бы пути не рушились при перемещении страницы в каталоги?

Comment: нет,  магического способа нет... но можно просто через notepad++ или любую IDE спокойно заменить пути сразу во всё проекте, если надо

Comment: `require __DIR__.'/../includes/header.php';` возможно что-то такое использовать

Comment: Это не поможет, так как если прописать новые пути в хедере, то он будет открываться через каталог, но перестанет отобразаться из корня! Единственный путь вижу отслеживать текущее положение, сохранять его в переменную и выводить на тех страницах, куда перешел в данный момент

Comment: @Jour да, я пробовал, но если вар_дампить __DIR__ то показывается полный путь, если к нему лепить `../../` то они прописываются в пути, а не возвращают на каталог выше

Comment: @YummyCocktail почему бы просто не использовать абсолютный путь всегда и везде)

Comment: @Jour прошу показать краткий пример)

Comment: @YummyCocktail пример.. даже не знаю) например `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` вернет абсолютный путь к корню сайта)

Comment: Можно прописать для каждого пути константу в виде const INCLUDES_PATH = __DIR__ . 'includes/'; и дальше в зависимости где лежат ваши файлы, менять переменную, а подключать страницы как require INCLUDES_PATH . 'nav.php';